# How to wait for a child directive render?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have a directive which uses another directive:

```html
<div style="border:2px solid black;height:150px;padding:10px">
     <my-internal-directive></my-internal-directive>
     <my-internal-directive></my-internal-directive>
     <my-internal-directive></my-internal-directive>
</div>
```

The internal directive:

```html
<h2>foo</h2>
```

The internal directive controller:

```js
internalDirectiveModule.directive('myInternalDirective', function($document){
    return {
      restrict:'E',
      scope: {},
      //templateUrl: 'myInternalDirective.html',    // EXTERNAL directive render first
      template: '<h2>foo</h2>',                     // INTERNAL directive render first
      link: function(scope, element){
        $document.find('body').append('<h1>internal directive\n');
      }  
    };
});
```

The problem is when I use `templateUrl` for the internal directive the external one renders first, but when I use `template` - the internal directive renders first. I have to get data from the internal directive inside the external one after the internal one renders (`link` method is called), but I can't reach this behavior because I suppose to use `templateUrl` only. How can I get data from a renderred child directive inside the `link` method of a parent one?

[DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/AXb1fLNNBOqwSAH3kgBh?p=preview)

Comment: Can you elaborate more on what you are trying to achieve? This seems like a strange use case for me.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of a function, set `link` to an object containing a `post` function.

```
link: { post: function() {  }  }
```

[post-linking-function documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile#post-linking-function)

Answer (score 0):

You can try a couple of things:

1. Set the priority of the the inner directive higher than the priority of the outer directive.
2. Fire the link function of the outer directive after a timeout like this:

   link: function () { $timeout(linkFn, 1000, false); }

Updated:
Here's an example for setting priority:

```
    angular.module('abc').directive('xyz', directive);

    directive.$inject = ['$timeout'];

    function directive($timeout) {

            return {
                    restrict: 'A',
                    priority: 100,
                    link: function ($scope, $element) {
```

Comment: Ok. Thanks for the answer, but how to set the priority?

Comment: In the directive definition, you can specify like this: priority: 100

Comment: I'm afraid but `priority` works only for attribute directives.

Comment: You mean `$timeout(linkFn, 1000)`? Do you think it is a good idea?

Comment: I would like to know whether it works for you or not. If yes then you at least have a fallback mechanism. Also, I don't think it'll break randomly. The solution if it works will work always. So, it a pragmatic solution.

Answer (score 0):

As told by Sidharth &  Arlen , you can set priority or in normal ways if it's not mandatory to have this scope: {} in your code than you can do it pretty easily using two way data binding in directives.  https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive.